# Query nested Realm objects encapsulated in RealmList into RealmResults

Tags: android, realm, realm-base-adapter

I have the following RealmObject:

```
public class City extends RealmObject {
    private String cityId;
    private RealmList<Street> streets;

    public String getId() {
        return cityId;
    }

    public void setCityId(String cityId) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }

    public RealmList<Street> getStreets() {
        return streets;
    }

    public void setStreets(RealmList<Street> streets) {
        this.streets = streets;
    }
}
```

Now having a cityId I need to query streets of particular city. How to do that? What I did try was:

```
    Realm.getInstance(context).where(City.class).equalTo("cityId", someCityId, false)
         .findFirst().getStreets().where().findAll()
```

But this leads into an Exception. I need to display streets in a `ListView` implementing filtering so I need streets to be `RealmResults` to use `RealmBaseAdapter<Street>`.

Comment: `implementing filtering` waaaaaait a second, what do you need filtering for? The android `Filter` interface and stuff runs on a background thread. It will cause a `RealmAccessedFromWrongThreadException` or whatever it is called.

Comment: how are you filtering? This question is incomplete.

Comment: Ok, its not the real filtering interface implementation, just a `public void filter` method which calls updateRealmResults(). It doesn't really maters, the question is about query mostly. What it does - it searches using .contains("streetName", searchText, false)

Comment: What Exception are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to have an open Realm instance either opened in your Activity in `onCreate()` and closed in `onDestroy()`, or [in your custom application class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31148661/2413303).

Then you can use this realm instance to query the realm

```
City city = realm.where(City.class).equalTo("cityId", cityId).findFirst();
```

Then you can access the `RealmList<T>` like any other list

```
RealmList<Street> streets = city.getStreets();
```

Then you can use a recyclerview to get the view for a given index within your `streets` list.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I want to use `RealmBaseAdapter` which is not applicable to `RealmList<T>` but to `RealmResults`.

Comment: You literally just need to use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31188310/2413303 and replace the RealmResults<T> with RealmList<T>, lol.

Comment: Ok, but I can't filter streets to make the List searchable, I need to create some ArrayList from that RealmList and thats what I am trying to avoid. So, like I'd pointed in a comment of my question the main question is the query. I need to query list of streets of one city. ListView is optional and I can manage it if I will get how to query streets of a city without City  by itself.

Comment: You see, everything you wrote in your answer doesn't answer the main question - How to query streets of a city. Not the City with  RealmList<Street> but streets alone.

Comment: Oh! You can either put the cityId in your street class next to the navigational property City (which is what we did) and just do `realm.where(Street.class).equalTo("cityId", cityId).findAll().equalTo("name", "something").findAll()` or use `realm.where(Street.class).equalTo("city.id", cityId).findAll();` the second one was slower though so we ditched it.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but this requires to redefine the existing models and DB. But its interesting to me if its possible to query streets of a city with existing model. You see, if I will use sqlite then I will build the relations between city and its streets manually. So it will be clear to me how to query streets of a city and its obvious to use cityId in child table. However Realm does build relations between city and its streets list already so the only question is: how? And is it possible to make desired query cuz seems like it doesn't.

Comment: Actually I made 2 models now - City with no list of streets inside and Street which has cityId and all the Street related fields, so now I made relations manually and its sux actually cuz I was hoping that realm does it for me.

Comment: Your city should have a realm list of streets, and your street should have the City as a realm object, and if you want to optimize the query then also the cityId. You are probably testing and developing and not in production yet, so just set the realm configuration to drop the tables on migration.

Comment: By the way, they have since added `RealmOrderedCollection` and the base adapter supports both `RealmList` and `RealmResults` now.