# After adding RealmList to RealmObject list is set to 0

Tags: java, android, realm

I have two RealmObjects, `CompanyInfo` and `Rooms`, one of which holds a RealmList of the other. When trying to add to that RealmList and then add it to the RealmObject after committing the transaction the RealmList is set to 0 and added to the RealmObject as a size 0, because of this when I populate the list of `Rooms` nothing shows up.  Why is this?

CompanyInfo class

```
public class CompanyInfo extends RealmObject{
    private String Name;
    private String Address;
    private String Contact;
    private String sqFt;
    private String taxed;
    private String concerns;
    private RealmList<Rooms> rooms;

    public RealmList<Rooms> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public void setRooms(RealmList<Rooms> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return Contact;
    }

    public String getSqFt() {
        return sqFt;
    }

    public String getTaxed() {
        return taxed;
    }

    public String getConcerns() {
        return concerns;
    }

    public void setName(String coName) {
        this.Name = coName;
    }

    public void setAddress(String coAddress) {
        this.Address = coAddress;
    }

    public void setContact(String coContact) {
        this.Contact = coContact;
    }

    public void setSqFt(String sqFt) {
        this.sqFt = sqFt;
    }

    public void setTaxed(String taxed) {
        this.taxed = taxed;
    }

    public void setConcerns(String concerns) {
        this.concerns = concerns;
    }

}
```

Rooms class

```
public class Rooms extends RealmObject{
    private String Name;
    private RealmList<FixtureInfo> fixtureInfos;

    public RealmList<FixtureInfo> getFixtureInfos() {
        return fixtureInfos;
    }

    public void setFixtureInfos(RealmList<FixtureInfo> fixtureInfos) {
        this.fixtureInfos = fixtureInfos;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }


}
```

Java file

```
public class RoomList extends ActionBarActivity {

    public AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
    public RealmList<Rooms> myRooms;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_room_list);

        populateListView();

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.RoomsList);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    default:
                        SaveInfo();
                        Intent i = new Intent(RoomList.this, RoomDescription.class);
                        TextView textItem = (TextView) view;
                        String txtString = textItem.getText().toString();
                        i.putExtra("txtString", txtString);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                }

            }

        });

        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
        CompanyInfo result = realm.where(CompanyInfo.class).findFirst();
        if (result != null){
            myRooms = result.getRooms();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LoadInfo();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SaveInfo();
    }

    private void setRoomName()
    {
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText txtInput = new EditText(this);
        final  Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);


        dialogBuilder.setTitle("New Room");
        dialogBuilder.setMessage("What is the room name?");
        dialogBuilder.setView(txtInput);
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                realm.beginTransaction();
                String txtString = txtInput.getText().toString();
                Rooms rooms = realm.createObject(Rooms.class);
                rooms.setName(txtString);
                myRooms.add(rooms);
                realm.commitTransaction();
                realm.close();
                SaveInfo();
                Intent i = new Intent(RoomList.this, RoomDescription.class);
                i.putExtra("txtString", txtString);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Room has been added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                populateListView();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                SaveInfo();
            }
        });


        AlertDialog dialogFixtureName = dialogBuilder.create();
        dialogFixtureName.show();
    }

    private void populateListView()
    {
        if (myRooms != null) {
            ArrayAdapter<Rooms> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Rooms>(this, R.layout.rooms, myRooms);

            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.RoomsList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            SaveInfo();
        }
    }

    public void SaveInfo()
    {
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
        CompanyInfo companyInfo = realm.where(CompanyInfo.class).findFirst();

        realm.beginTransaction();
        companyInfo.setRooms(myRooms);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
    }

    public void LoadInfo()
    {
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
        CompanyInfo companyInfo = realm.where(CompanyInfo.class).findFirst();
        if (companyInfo != null){
            myRooms = companyInfo.getRooms();
        }
        realm.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_room_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.add:
                setRoomName();
                break;
            case R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPage.class));
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are opening FOUR realm instances and you are closing NONE OF THEM. Read the documentation for how to actually use Realm.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've closed my instances and the RealmList still isn't adding correctly, is there anything else I am not seeing that could cause this?

Comment: Can you edit the bug fix into the question? Typically you either have 1 realm instance per activity, or if you are hacky enough then 1 realm instance for the application (on the UI thread).

Comment: Added the edited version with the close statements. I tried to use only one realm instance like you had mentioned and received `NullPointerExceptions`

Comment: Check out this answer to better understand Realm: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30567237/2413303 you cannot use a RealmObject that is associated with a realm that is closed, if you go the Activity onCreate/onDestroy route, then you open a single Realm in your onCreate, and close it in onDestroy. I personally prefer to open in Application (the answer under the linked one) because Realm currently waits for the transaction to complete on open which can cause ANR, but that takes more setting up.