# EventBus only works when put in Handler

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, realm

I have `ViewPager` which contains three different `Fragments`, every fragment has it's own API call. Let's say that first fragment is requesting something from API. Callback is returned, then I am saving it to local `Realm` database and after that I am sending it with `EventBus` to Fragment. The problem is that I get `No subscribers registered for event class` error and nothing happens.

After some time I managed to solve this in this way :

```
final GetInfoResponse response = new GetInfoResponse(databaseService.getInfo());
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        EventBus.getDefault().post(response);
                    }
                });
```

If I put EventBus in Handler  the `Event` is delivered properly to Fragment.

I was thinking that maybe `Realm` is switching threads when it gets data from database. But I am not sure. On the other side, if I am not doing local saving and send `EventBus` straight from REST Callback, everything works fine.

EDIT : 
`GetInfo` method

```
public List<Information> getInfo() {
        List<Information> informationList;
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(getConfig(context));
        realm.beginTransaction();
        RealmResults<Information> realmList = realm.where(Information.class).findAll();
        informationList = new ArrayList<>(realmList);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        return informationList;
    }
```

Why is it so, and how can I do it better?

EDIT 2 :
After changes proposed by @EpicPandaForce.
This is my code structure and path to call API.
I have Fragment. Let's call it `InfoFragment`. In `onCreateView` I am doing this :

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info, container, false);
            realm = Realm.getInstance(DatabaseConfiguration.getConfig(getActivity()));
            DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(realm, getActivity());
            dataManager.getInfo();
            return view;
        }

        public void onEvent(GetFaqCategoriesResponse response) {
        ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
            super.onStop();
        }
```

Now, my `DataManager` looks like this :

```
public DataManager(Realm realm, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        databaseService = new DatabaseService(realm);
    }

public void getInfo() {
        if (ConnectionUtils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
            ServerService.getInfo(this);
        } else {
            final GetInfoResponse response
                    = new GetInfoResponse(databaseService.getInfo());
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    EventBus.getDefault().post(response);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

My `DatabaseService` :

```
private Realm realm;

public SupportDatabaseService(Realm realm) {
    this.realm = realm;
}

public List<Info> getInfo() {
    RealmResults<Info> realmList = realm.where(Info.class).findAll();
    return new ArrayList<>(realmList);
}
```

I am closing `Realm` instance with `realm.close()` in `onDestroyView` of `InfoFragment`.

Comment: Are you using `onEvent()` or `onEventMainThread()`?

Comment: I am using onEvent()

Comment: And are you trying to send it to the main thread, or are you trying to send it to the same thread with a delay?

Comment: I have edited previous answer. `Handler().post` works also, no need to delay. I am not trying to send it on any thread on purpose. I am just getting data from `Realm` database and want to send it via EventBus. And I suppose that 'Realm' is switching threads somehow that's why normally `EventBus` is not send and I need to put it in `Handler` so the Thread matches. I guess

Comment: What thread did you open the Realm on? `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()`? Or on a background thread ?

Comment: I create it in Fragment in `onCreateView` I will edit main post to show how `databaseService.getInfo()` look like

Comment: Ah, you **are** opening the realm on the background thread. That explains everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically update the Realms on all looper threads, Realm [sends a message to the main thread looper's handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567237/2413303) to start updating when you commit a transaction. So unless you are subscribed to the Realm's changes in a `RealmListener` (which I don't recommend as it updates every single time the realm is modified!), you will only receive the notification about it when the next handler cycle runs. If you use `onEvent()`, then as specified for the [default threading mode](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md), your event will be delivered immediately and not through a handler (which sends a runnable to execute on the other looper thread on next iteration).

Basically, if you don't send it through the handler, then the Realm of the other thread won't be updated yet at the time of receiving the event. If you are sending these Realm objects from the main thread to the main thread, you can use `onEventMainThread()` instead of `onEvent()` to automatically pass it through a handler to the main thread.

By the way, you are using Realm incorrectly, the Realm instances you open should also be closed, but a Realm object associated with a given Realm can only be accessed on that same thread, and a Realm object can only be accessed from an open realm. You don't need to open a new realm to execute the query, you could just use `findAll()` on your main thread using the Realm instance you opened in `onCreateView()` as you also close it in `onDestroyView()`, and `findAll()` is executed as a lazy query and therefore isn't memory intensive whatsoever. And you're also beginning and committing a transaction even though you're not actually doing any writes...? :P

Comment: I wouldn't completely say your problem is resolved, however. You **are** opening a Realm that you don't close, and you're committing a transaction that isn't actually a writing operation. I'd look into whether you're using Realm correctly or incorrectly elsewhere as well.

Comment: It explains why this happens, so it answers my question. About Realm - my bad, thought that commiting is this closing operation you are refering. Thanks ;)

Comment: Well, fixed my mistakes with Realm, now instances are created correctly. This haven't fixed issue forcing me to post with Handler. Tried also `realm.refresh()`, but with no effect.

Comment: Yes, still get `No subscribers registered for event class `

Comment: Do you have a method with the setup `public void onEventMainThread(GetInfoResponse getInfoResponse) {...}`?

Comment: Yes, I have also tried other thread options. I think this problem is described here : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads . So only other way would be implementing listener which is more boilerplate than Handler.

Comment: No, this has not been a problem for me. When do you subscribe the fragment to the bus?

Comment: OnStart() runs AFTER your operation is complete, that's all. Your fragment isn't registered yet at the time. Consider registering in onCreateView and unregistering in onDestroyView.